# Display a Circle in XML

Tags: android

I have created a `drawable` file called `activity_cirle` which is creating a circle and is being reference and displayed in `activity_negative` as an `imageView`. In the preview of `activity_negative` the circle appears as a circle but when I run the app it appears as a square. How would you solve this?

#### activity_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid
    android:color="#666666"/>

<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp" />

</shape>
```

#### activity_negative.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBlack">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/acton_bar_imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_app_icon" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/topBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGuru"
                android:layout_width="71dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="handleClick"
                android:text="GURU" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSolve"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:onClick="handleClick"
                android:text="SOLVE" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLearn"
                android:layout_width="79dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:onClick="handleClick"
                android:text="LEARN" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPower"
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:onClick="handleClick"
                android:text="POWER" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:text="Question"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="24dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
            android:background="@drawable/activity_circle"
            android:clickable="false"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->

            <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:orientation="horizontal">-->

                <!--<Button-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/btnNext"-->
                    <!--android:text="Next"-->
                    <!--android:textStyle="bold"-->
                    <!--android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>-->

            <!--</LinearLayout>-->

        <!--</LinearLayout>-->

        <!--<TextView-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnClockwise"
                    android:text="Clockwise"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnAntiClockwise"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Anti-Clockwise"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnAntiClockwiseFaster"
                android:text="Anti-Clockwise Fast"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

                <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnAntiClockwiseSlower"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Anti-Clockwise Slow"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnClockwiseFaster"
                    android:text="Clockwise Fast"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnClockwiseSlower"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Clockwise Slow"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnSmall"
            android:text="Small"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnLarge"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnBlue"
            android:text="Blue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnRed"
            android:text="Red"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: instead of using background try using src

Comment: @MDDanishAnsari thanks its working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `background` try using `src`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"  //here
        android:layout_height="120dp" //here
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
        android:background="@drawable/activity_circle"
        android:clickable="false"/>
```

use same height and width... both should be same for perfect circle shape

Answer (score 0):

change only height and width of image view below code..

```
            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
            android:background="@drawable/activity_circle"
            android:clickable="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

android:background will set image as per imageview area. while src is used for foreground image.

put this in bg_circle.xml in drawable folder.

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#1dea0d"/>

    <size
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"/> </shape>
</shape>
```

put this in src="@drawable/bg_circle" in imageview.